# how to get the index of a sectioned cell of a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I would like to get the index number of a selected cell from a sectioned tableview. I give the user the option to switch tableview from standard to sectioned.  when it's in standard view I get the selected index with this line

```
NSString *myIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", inedxPath.row];
```

How would I get that same string in sectioned TableView ???

I have been toying with

```
NSString *myIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.Section inedxPath.row];
```

...Hope that makes sense..Thx...??????

context:
 I store the index number in a dictionary and when the user comes back to the tableview the app should remind them what they selected prior by changing the Product Name text color to gray in that selected cell...I do this by saving all the index numbers of selected products and when they come back change the text color of only the index's in my list. hope that helps.
[image: mySectionedTable]

and thanks again

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. In a table with sections, any particular row has both a section value (indexPath.section) and a row value (indexPath.row). Do you want myIndex to show both numbers?  What are you using myIndex for? Note, in your code, you have Section with a capital s, that's wrong.

Comment: @rdelmar, well, I store the index number in a dictionary and when the user comes back to the tableview the app should remind them what they selected prior by changing the Product Name text color to gray in that selected cell...I do this by saving all the index numbers of selected products and when they come back change the text color of only the index's in my list.  hope that helps.

Comment: Then you should just store indexPath itself, since it encompasses both the section and row values.

Comment: agree with @rdelmar, it's best to go and save the indexPath object itself.

Comment: @rdelmar I just logged it your are correct indexPath does give you both...I did not know that thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the indexPath object itself in an array, not a dictionary. Then in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method use an if clause to test whether your array contains indexPath, and if so, color that cell's text gray.

After Edit:

If you create a mutable array called indexPathArray, then in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method, add a line to put the indexPath in the array:

```
[self.indexPathArray addObject:indexPath];
```

In the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, add this code to color the selected cells gray:

```
if ([self.indexPathArray containsObject:indexPath]) 
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

You would put this code in above where you set the textLabel's text value. Depending on what else is going on in your app, you probably should add a [self.tableView reloadData] line to the viewDidAppear method, so the table view will be updated and show your gray text.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  If it's not too much trouble can you give a small code example.  I can post the way I do it but i fear it may confuse more than help.  Thx